# How to add a different DOMAIN ADDRESS to my Google Sheet Add-On?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-workspace, google-workspace-add-ons

Our app is designed to be used by our internal users most of the time. However, we have a partner company that we are planning to give access to our app. In other words, some users are outside of our domain but within our partner company's domain.

Would it be possible if we deploy the app internally and add OUR PARTNER'S DOMAIN in the allowed list?

Comment: I think that you will have to ask your domain administrator to add your partener domain as a trusted domain. Are you the domaini administrador or someone else?

Comment: @Rubén
Thank you for your answer. In my case, I am the regular user in our domain. Since it is our first project with the Google Cloud Platform. Could you please give some guidance on where to/how to add our partner's domain address?

Comment: Perhaps your partner domain should be added as an alias domain. Anyway To learn about trusted domains and alias domains in Google Workspace go to https://support.google.com/a .

Comment: Refer this [document](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6160020?hl=en#zippy=%2Cadd-a-trusted-domain-to-your-allowlist) for more information

Comment: @Rubén Thank you for your answer. As you told me, I contacted Google and I was able to get a helpful answer.

Comment: @SaiChandiniRouthu Thank you, this document has been very helpful.

Comment: @ whytili I have posted the same as an answer, can you upvote and accept it for better community reach.